# Comparison of different covariance function for GP model?

Tags: machine-learning, covariance, nonlinear-regression, gaussian-process

Currently I am using squared exponential covariance function for GP model construction for non linear model. It seems Squared exponential covariance work well however I do not have any idea which covariance would might work instead of squared exponential covariance functions. I am using matlab tool for GP model construction, I would be happy if I can get some covariance of similar characteristics of squared exponential.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your problem, it's difficult to say which kernels might work better. The squared exponential kernel is often cited as being "too smooth" to be realistic.

In terms of other options, a good starting place might be the [kernel cookbook](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~duvenaud/cookbook/index.html), which has a nice list of other covariance kernels with illustrations and some intuitions. The author of the kernel cookbook also has [code](https://github.com/jamesrobertlloyd/gp-structure-search) which automatically searches for a good kernel given your data (using Matlab and numpy). There are also a number of examples given in [chapter 4 of the Gaussian process](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW4.pdf) book.  If you are interested in implementations, the julia [Gaussian Processes package](https://github.com/STOR-i/GaussianProcesses.jl/tree/master/src/kernels) has quite a few kernel implementations and generally similar syntax to Matlab.